# Read x lines of custom formatted text file, skipping n lines

Tags: r

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
                                                      DATE                                                                    NETWORK
GROUP ID                          AVERAGE CONC     (YYMMDDHH)             RECEPTOR  (XR, YR, ZELEV, ZHILL, ZFLAG)    OF TYPE  GRID-ID
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
  
ALL      HIGH   1ST HIGH VALUE IS    3822.82070  ON 88011803: AT (  500000.00,  4000150.00,     0.00,     0.00,    0.00)  GC  GRID1   
         HIGH   2ND HIGH VALUE IS    3376.11752  ON 88011803: AT (  500000.00,  4000000.00,     0.00,     0.00,    0.00)  GC  GRID1   
         HIGH   3RD HIGH VALUE IS    2563.76151  ON 88022706: AT (  500200.00,  4000000.00,     0.00,     0.00,    0.00)  GC  GRID1   
         HIGH   4TH HIGH VALUE IS    2033.30514  ON 88010224: AT (  500050.00,  4000050.00,     0.00,     0.00,    0.00)  GC  GRID1
```

The data appears about halfway through the file (say line 102839) and I only need the first two rows of data.

I want an data.frame output that looks like this:

```
  SRCGROUP          Value     Conc YYMMDDHH X_coord Y_coord Zelev Zhill ZFLAG
1      ALL 1ST HIGH VALUE 6099.915  8801222  500050 4000050     0     0     0
2      ALL 2ND HIGH VALUE 6001.993 88011801  500100 4000100     0     0     0
```

Right now, I `grep` to the line I want to start reading (`row + 9`) and then `readLines` the number of lines I want (`row + 9 + values_to_read`).  However, then my output is a character vector so I can't figure out how to make it a data.frame that is separated where I need.

## I tried this (and many other iterations)

```
temp <- 
  readLines(file_name)[(row + 9):(row + 9+values_to_read)] 

out <- data.frame(SRCGROUP = temp[,1:9],
                  Value = temp[,15:19],
                  Conc = temp[,33:48],
                  YYMMDDHH = temp[,52:60],
                  X_coord = temp[,66:77],
                  Y_coord = temp[,80:90],
                  Zelev = temp[,91:100],
                  Zhill = temp[,101:110],
                  ZFLAG = temp[,111:119]
                  )
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at `read.table` and make there use of `nrows` and `skip`?

Comment: I looked into read.table previously, but I couldn't figure out how to do the custom file separation that is based on character spacing.  Its possible I overlooked that though.

Comment: Maybe `read.fwf` can be used in this case?

Comment: Seems like your text file has TABs as field delimiters. Is that right? If yes, at what positions?

Comment: No it has spaces between most columns, but also spaces between the words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps in some way:

```
library(readr)
begin <- c(0,9,33,52,66,80,91,101,111)
end <- c(9,19,48,60,77,90,100,110,119)
col_names <- c("SRCGROUP", "Value", "Conc", "YYMMDDHH", "X_coord", "Y_coord", 
               "Zelev", "Zhill", "ZFLAG")


col_pos <- list("begin" = begin, "end" = end, "col_names" = col_names)
read_fwf("test.txt", col_positions = col_pos, 
         skip = 4) |> 
  tidyr::fill(SRCGROUP)
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 4 × 9
  SRCGROUP Value       Conc YYMMDDHH X_coord Y_coord Zelev Zhill ZFLAG
  <chr>    <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 ALL      HIGH   1ST 3823. 88011803  500000 4000150     0     0     0
2 ALL      HIGH   2ND 3376. 88011803  500000 4000000     0     0     0
3 ALL      HIGH   3RD 2564. 88022706  500200 4000000     0     0     0
4 ALL      HIGH   4TH 2033. 88010224  500050 4000050     0     0     0
```

Comment: This was almost! Thank you! Made the following minor change:    out <- read_fwf(file_name, col_positions = col_pos, 
                 skip = (row + 8), n_max = values_to_read) |> 
          tidyr::fill(SRCGROUP)

Answer (score 0):

If your data has <kbd>TAB</kbd>s as delimiters like so (`^I` == <kbd>TAB</kbd>)

```
$ cat -t file
                                                      DATE                                                                    NETWORK
GROUP ID                          AVERAGE CONC     (YYMMDDHH)             RECEPTOR  (XR, YR, ZELEV, ZHILL, ZFLAG)    OF TYPE  GRID-ID
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

ALL^IHIGH^I1ST HIGH VALUE IS^I3822.82070^ION 88011803: AT (^I500000.00,^I4000150.00,^I0.00,^I0.00,^I0.00)^IGC^IGRID1
   ^IHIGH^I2ND HIGH VALUE IS^I3376.11752^ION 88011803: AT (^I500000.00,^I4000000.00,^I0.00,^I0.00,^I0.00)^IGC^IGRID2
   ^IHIGH^I3RD HIGH VALUE IS^I2563.76151^ION 88022706: AT (^I500200.00,^I4000000.00,^I0.00,^I0.00,^I0.00)^IGC^IGRID1
   ^IHIGH^I4TH HIGH VALUE IS^I2033.30514^ION 88010224: AT (^I500050.00,^I4000050.00,^I0.00,^I0.00,^I0.00)^IGC^IGRID1
```

Reading the data

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

df <- read_delim('file', 
                 delim="\t",
                 skip=4,
                 n_max=2,
                 col_names=c("SRCGROUP", "H", "Value", "Conc", 
                             "YYMMDDHH", "X_coord", "Y_coord", 
                             "Zelev", "Zhill", "ZFLAG"))
```

Filtering and correcting

```
df %>% 
  select(-H, -starts_with("X1")) %>% 
  mutate(SRCGROUP = SRCGROUP[1], 
         YYMMDDHH = as.numeric(sub(".* (\\d+):.*", "\\1", YYMMDDHH)), 
         ZFLAG = as.numeric(sub(")", "", ZFLAG)))
# A tibble: 2 × 9
  SRCGROUP Value              Conc YYMMDDHH X_coord Y_coord Zelev Zhill ZFLAG
  <chr>    <chr>             <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 ALL      1ST HIGH VALUE IS 3823. 88011803  500000 4000150     0     0     0
2 ALL      2ND HIGH VALUE IS 3376. 88011803  500000 4000000     0     0     0
```